# sencha touch: the width of tab bar not extend to screen width

Tags: sencha-touch

I place tabPanel's tabBar on top postion and keep bottom style, so refer to [this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?102839), and the display result is ok but the tab bar not extend all space, at the top right corner of page shows background. ( about 30px at my 1024px resolution).
when use Chrome to view it, if I open Developer Tools and then close it, then tab bar becomes ok. (occupy all screen with).
I try tabPanel.doLayout() or viewPort.doLayout(), both not works.

Please give any advice, Thank you !

```
var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
        id:'tabPanel',  
        tabBar : {
            dock : 'top',
            layout : { pack : 'right' },
        },
        listeners: {
                single: true,
                afterlayout: function (panel) {
                    var dom = Ext.select('.x-docked-top', panel.getEl().dom).first().dom;
                    dom.className = dom.className.replace('x-docked-top', 'x-docked-bottom');                   
                }
        },
        defaults: {
                scroll: 'vertical'
        },
        cardSwitchAnimation: {
            type: 'slide',
            duration: 1
        },
        flex: 1,
        ui: 'light',
        items : [
            {
                iconCls : 'icon1',
                items: [ scanPanel ]        
            },
            {
                iconCls : 'icon2',
                items: [ logPanel ]         
            }
        ]       
});
```

...

```
var viewPort = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen : true,
    layout : {
        type : 'fit',
        align : 'stretch'
    },
    items : [ tabPanel]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the Ext.Panel has a default setting for padding, try to move the tabBar into Ext.Panel.